# How Do I Use Case Statement Column In Group By

Tags: sql, db2

As stated by the question, I'm trying to formulate a query that has a case statement in the column results, and then I want to include that column in the query's group by statement. To give a concrete example, here is all little of what my query looks like:

```
SELECT SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN1, OTHER_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN2,
CASE
    WHEN SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'A'
    ELSE 'B'
END AS CASE_COLUMN
FROM SOME_TABLE SOME_TABLE_ALIAS
... (other table joins and where clauses)
GROUP BY SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN1, OTHER_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN2, CASE_COLUMN
```

Before coming here, I checked out a few websites, including [this one](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1116474), to try solve my problem. I've tried adding another alias after the `CASE` keyword like is shown in the linked web page but have had no luck. The error message I continue to receive is the following:

```
[Error] Script lines: 127-151 ----------------------
 CASE_COLUMN IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.53.71
```

Has anyone else run into the issues I'm facing and been able to use a `GROUP BY` on the results of a `CASE` statement? Any help would be appreciated. Oh, and the DB2 version is a z/OS instance, version 10 (DSN10015)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The alias isn't available to use in the GROUP BY because when GROUP BY happens the alias isn't defined yet:

```
Here's the order:
1.FROM
2.WHERE
3.GROUP BY
4.HAVING
5.SELECT
6.ORDER BY
```

You can work around that with:

```
SELECT column1,column2,case_column
FROM (
SELECT SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN1, OTHER_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN2,
CASE
    WHEN SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'A'
    ELSE 'B'
END AS CASE_COLUMN
FROM SOME_TABLE SOME_TABLE_ALIAS
... (other table joins and where clauses)
) a
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, CASE_COLUMN
```

Or just use the case you use in SELECT in GROUP BY

Comment: Correct.  Just to clarify however, in [IBM parlance] if you say `FROM some_table as sta`, then 'sta' would be termed "correlation name" in the [FROM table-reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html), rather than an ["alias" name](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000910.html). But this points out, that as your own answer shows, the FROM clause (with the correlation name) is evaluated first, before the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 9):

You can either use the case as is in the group by, like this:

```
SELECT SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN1, OTHER_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN2,
CASE
    WHEN SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'A'
    ELSE 'B'
END AS CASE_COLUMN
FROM SOME_TABLE SOME_TABLE_ALIAS
... (other table joins and where clauses)
GROUP BY SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN1, OTHER_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN2, 
CASE
    WHEN SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'A'
    ELSE 'B'
END
```

or use a sub-query like this:

```
select COLUMN1, COLUMN2, CASE_COLUMN
from (
    SELECT SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN1, OTHER_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN2,
    CASE
        WHEN SOME_TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'A'
        ELSE 'B'
    END AS CASE_COLUMN
    FROM SOME_TABLE SOME_TABLE_ALIAS
    ... (other table joins and where clauses)
) a
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, CASE_COLUMN
```

Comment: This answer and Filipe's came in at virtually the same time and unfortunately I can only pick one. This answer is also a very helpful, thank you.